# Mongo Find complete at 0.105 sec, But count takes 1.0059 sec: Total 30024 records

Tags: mongodb

My Count query is very slow. I have made the indexes and believe hence the Find query return records in 0.105 sec.

```
db.collectionname.find({}) => 0.105 sec
```

When do count with the same query it takes 1.0059 sec.

```
db.collectionname.count({}) => 1.0059 sec
```

There are 2L records in total in my collection and search result is 30024 records.

Please guide me what are the steps I need to take?

## Mongo Version is : 3.2

```
db.getCollection('beta').find({"status":"1",
    "type.und.value":"beta","state":{"$in":["a","b"]},
"changed":{"$gte":1463804682},"uid":{"$ne":"333"},
"price":{"$ne":[]}}).explain()
```

> /* 1 */ {
>       "queryPlanner" : {
>           "plannerVersion" : 1,
>           "namespace" : "beta",
>           "indexFilterSet" : false,
>           "parsedQuery" : {
>               "$and" : [ 
>                   {
>                       "type.und.value" : {
>                           "$eq" : "beta"
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "status" : {
>                           "$eq" : "1"
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "changed" : {
>                           "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "state" : {
>                           "$in" : [ 
>                               "a", 
>                               "b"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "$not" : {
>                           "price" : {
>                               "$eq" : []
>                           }
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "$not" : {
>                           "uid" : {
>                               "$eq" : "333"
>                           }
>                       }
>                   }
>               ]
>           },
>           "winningPlan" : {
>               "stage" : "FETCH",
>               "filter" : {
>                   "$and" : [ 
>                       {
>                           "type.und.value" : {
>                               "$eq" : "beta"
>                           }
>                       }, 
>                       {
>                           "status" : {
>                               "$eq" : "1"
>                           }
>                       }, 
>                       {
>                           "state" : {
>                               "$in" : [ 
>                                   "a", 
>                                   "b"
>                               ]
>                           }
>                       }, 
>                       {
>                           "$not" : {
>                               "price" : {
>                                   "$eq" : []
>                               }
>                           }
>                       }, 
>                       {
>                           "$not" : {
>                               "uid" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "333"
>                               }
>                           }
>                       }
>                   ]
>               },
>               "inputStage" : {
>                   "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                   "keyPattern" : {
>                       "changed" : 1.0
>                   },
>                   "indexName" : "changed_1",
>                   "isMultiKey" : false,
>                   "isUnique" : false,
>                   "isSparse" : false,
>                   "isPartial" : false,
>                   "indexVersion" : 1,
>                   "direction" : "forward",
>                   "indexBounds" : {
>                       "changed" : [ 
>                           "[1463804682.0, inf.0]"
>                       ]
>                   }
>               }
>           },
>           "rejectedPlans" : [ 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "type.und.value" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "beta"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "status" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "1"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "changed" : {
>                                   "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "uid" : 1.0
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "uid_1",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "uid" : [ 
>                               "[MinKey, \"333\")", 
>                               "(\"333\", MaxKey]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "type.und.value" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "beta"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "status" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "1"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "changed" : {
>                                   "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "uid" : {
>                                       "$eq" : "333"
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "price" : 1.0
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "price_1",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "price" : [ 
>                               "[MinKey, undefined)", 
>                               "(undefined, [])", 
>                               "([], MaxKey]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "status" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "1"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "changed" : {
>                                   "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "uid" : {
>                                       "$eq" : "333"
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "type.und.value" : 1.0
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "type.und.value_1",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "type.und.value" : [ 
>                               "[\"beta\", \"beta\"]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "type.und.value" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "beta"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "status" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "1"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "uid" : {
>                                       "$eq" : "333"
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "changed" : -1
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "_changed",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "changed" : [ 
>                               "[inf.0, 1463804682.0]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "type.und.value" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "beta"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "changed" : {
>                                   "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "uid" : {
>                                       "$eq" : "333"
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "status" : 1.0
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "status_1",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "status" : [ 
>                               "[\"1\", \"1\"]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>           ]
>       },
>       "serverInfo" : {
>           "host" : "xxx",
>           "port" : xxx,
>           "version" : "3.2.13",
>           "gitVersion" : "xxx"
>       },
>       "ok" : 1.0 }

==========================================

```
db.getCollection('beta').explain().count({"status":"1",
    "type.und.value":"beta","state":{"$in":["a","b"]},
"changed":{"$gte":1463804682},"uid":{"$ne":"333"},
"price":{"$ne":[]}})
```

> /* 1 */ {
>       "queryPlanner" : {
>           "plannerVersion" : 1,
>           "namespace" : "property.beta",
>           "indexFilterSet" : false,
>           "parsedQuery" : {
>               "$and" : [ 
>                   {
>                       "type.und.value" : {
>                           "$eq" : "beta"
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "status" : {
>                           "$eq" : "1"
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "changed" : {
>                           "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "state" : {
>                           "$in" : [ 
>                               "a", 
>                               "b"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "$not" : {
>                           "price" : {
>                               "$eq" : []
>                           }
>                       }
>                   }, 
>                   {
>                       "$not" : {
>                           "uid" : {
>                               "$eq" : "333"
>                           }
>                       }
>                   }
>               ]
>           },
>           "winningPlan" : {
>               "stage" : "FETCH",
>               "filter" : {
>                   "$and" : [ 
>                       {
>                           "type.und.value" : {
>                               "$eq" : "beta"
>                           }
>                       }, 
>                       {
>                           "status" : {
>                               "$eq" : "1"
>                           }
>                       }, 
>                       {
>                           "state" : {
>                               "$in" : [ 
>                                   "a", 
>                                   "b"
>                               ]
>                           }
>                       }, 
>                       {
>                           "$not" : {
>                               "price" : {
>                                   "$eq" : []
>                               }
>                           }
>                       }, 
>                       {
>                           "$not" : {
>                               "uid" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "333"
>                               }
>                           }
>                       }
>                   ]
>               },
>               "inputStage" : {
>                   "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                   "keyPattern" : {
>                       "changed" : 1.0
>                   },
>                   "indexName" : "changed_1",
>                   "isMultiKey" : false,
>                   "isUnique" : false,
>                   "isSparse" : false,
>                   "isPartial" : false,
>                   "indexVersion" : 1,
>                   "direction" : "forward",
>                   "indexBounds" : {
>                       "changed" : [ 
>                           "[1463804682.0, inf.0]"
>                       ]
>                   }
>               }
>           },
>           "rejectedPlans" : [ 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "type.und.value" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "beta"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "status" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "1"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "changed" : {
>                                   "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "uid" : 1.0
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "uid_1",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "uid" : [ 
>                               "[MinKey, \"333\")", 
>                               "(\"333\", MaxKey]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "type.und.value" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "beta"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "status" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "1"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "changed" : {
>                                   "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "uid" : {
>                                       "$eq" : "333"
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "price" : 1.0
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "price_1",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "price" : [ 
>                               "[MinKey, undefined)", 
>                               "(undefined, [])", 
>                               "([], MaxKey]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "status" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "1"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "changed" : {
>                                   "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "uid" : {
>                                       "$eq" : "333"
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "type.und.value" : 1.0
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "type.und.value_1",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "type.und.value" : [ 
>                               "[\"beta\", \"beta\"]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "type.und.value" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "beta"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "status" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "1"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "uid" : {
>                                       "$eq" : "333"
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "changed" : -1
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "_changed",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "changed" : [ 
>                               "[inf.0, 1463804682.0]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }, 
>               {
>                   "stage" : "FETCH",
>                   "filter" : {
>                       "$and" : [ 
>                           {
>                               "type.und.value" : {
>                                   "$eq" : "beta"
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "changed" : {
>                                   "$gte" : 1463804682.0
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "state" : {
>                                   "$in" : [ 
>                                       "a", 
>                                       "b"
>                                   ]
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "price" : {
>                                       "$eq" : []
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }, 
>                           {
>                               "$not" : {
>                                   "uid" : {
>                                       "$eq" : "333"
>                                   }
>                               }
>                           }
>                       ]
>                   },
>                   "inputStage" : {
>                       "stage" : "IXSCAN",
>                       "keyPattern" : {
>                           "status" : 1.0
>                       },
>                       "indexName" : "status_1",
>                       "isMultiKey" : false,
>                       "isUnique" : false,
>                       "isSparse" : false,
>                       "isPartial" : false,
>                       "indexVersion" : 1,
>                       "direction" : "forward",
>                       "indexBounds" : {
>                           "status" : [ 
>                               "[\"1\", \"1\"]"
>                           ]
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>           ]
>       },
>       "serverInfo" : {
>           "host" : "xxx",
>           "port" : xxx,
>           "version" : "3.2.13",
>           "gitVersion" : "xxx"
>       },
>       "ok" : 1.0 }

Comment: How do you do these queries? Are you using the `mongo` shell, or a driver? Please post the complete code and output that resulted in the timings you are seeing.

Comment: Hi kevin, I have added the information with explain() above. Can you please check?

Comment: The two explains are identical. They should not be. `count()` should have a query plan with a `COUNT` stage. Are you sure you posted the right information?

Comment: Sorry. My bad.. the reason is with RAM. When I have cleared the RAM the query execute much better. Thanks..